# How can handle this type of problem UnauthorizedAccessException Was handli Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have seen already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228560/unauthorizedaccessexception-when-using-directory-getfiles), but not a complete solve this problem. When I Read all find and include folder compiler meg throw a exception about the Unauthorized. Error throw compiler:

> Access to the path F:\System Volume information \ is Denied

my code is

```
private void toolStripButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Uri _urii = new Uri(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
        //            MessageBox.Show(_urii.Host);
        string _sthost = _urii.Host;

        string aa = "F:\\" + _sthost + " ";
        string[] _file = Directory.GetFiles("F:\\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories); //Exception here create
        foreach (var item in _file)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Length.ToString());
```

My question is **F** drive no have a **System Volume Information** folder.. why throw this type of exception?

Comment: my account has equal to admin......

Comment: Nit pick: in this case the compiler isn't issuing the error, it's the runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden + System folders don't showup when you do "dir" or look at files in explorer, but it does not mean they are not there.

The "System Volume Information" is present on non-read-only disks Windows touches and permissions setup in such a way that even admins don't have access (also you can gain one - same way to any other protected location - by getting ownership and adding access).

In general you should expect IO errors like "access denied" and handle them appropriately. I.e. simply ignoring all IO exceptions during file enumeration may be OK.

Note use this command (type in CMD console) to see attributes on that folder:

```
cd f:\ /d && attrib "System Volume Information"
```

Comment: Sir i have checked hidden files,not there any type of this file

Comment: string[] _file = Directory.GetFiles("F:\\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories); //Exception here create